# Are Sitecore events handled synchronously?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I want to hook the item:renamed event to do some processing.  It may take a few minutes though. Are event handlers executed asynchronously or synchronously with normal pipeline execution?  Is there a standard Sitecore way to kick this off asynchronously if I need to do that myself?

The only time this handler needs to execute is when an item is renamed in Content Editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Sitecore` events are executed synchronously. There is a `Sitecore Development Toolkit` module on `Sitecore Marketplace` which contains a code for firing events asynchronously which you can easily reuse in your solution  [Sitecore Development Toolkit](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Development_Toolkit.aspx).

Here is a part of their code which fires methods asynchronously when the event is fired:

```cs
public void OnItemRenamed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  if (args != null)
  {
    var item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
    Assert.IsNotNull(item, "No item in parameters");

    var name = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 1) as string;
    Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(name, "No name in parameters");

    DoAsync(() => OnItemRenameAsync(item, name));
  }
}

private void OnItemRenameAsync(Item item, string name)
{
  var itemRef = new ItemReference(item.Parent);
  var itemRefText = itemRef.ToString();
  // do some work here
}
```

Comment: If you look at their implementation of DoAsync(), they just call .BeginInvoke, which technically will run the task on another thread, but Sitecore does have a mechanism for launching background jobs.

Answer (score 3):

Sitecore events are synchronous. You can kick off your long running task as a job. First create a class to handle the event:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void ItemRenamed (object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Run("LongRenameTask");
        }

        protected void Run(string methodName, EventArgs args)
        {
            var item = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;
            var name = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 1) as string;
            RunJob(methodName, item, name);
        }

        protected Handle RunJob(string methodName, Item item, string name)
        {
            var options = new JobOptions(
                "Preparing rename job '{0}' for '{1}'".FormatWith(
                    methodName, 
                    item.ID.ToString()), 
                "item:renamed", 
                "shell", 
                new ItemRenamedManager(item, name), 
                methodName)
                    {
                        WriteToLog = true,
                        AtomicExecution = true,
                    };

            var job = new Job(options);
            JobManager.Start(job);

            return job.Handle;
        }

    }
}
```

Then create a class to do your work (this will be called on a background thread by Sitecore):

```cs
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ItemRenamedManager
    {
        protected Item RenamedItem { get; set; }
        protected string Name { get; set; }

        public ItemRenamedManager(Item item, string name)
        {
            RenamedItem = item;
            Name = name;
        }

        public void LongRenameTask()
        {
            // Do your long running task here. 
            // The property 'RenamedItem' will give you the item
        }
    }
}
```

Then patch your event handler in:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <events>
            <event name="item:renamed">
              <handler type="MyNamespace.MyClass" method="ItemRenamed" />
            </event>
        </events>
     </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The above code is cribbed a bit from memory and needs some error handling, but should be pretty close, but this way, your long running task won't block the Content Editor UI.